# How can you iterate through controllers in an ng-repeat from the parent?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, parent-child, ng-controller

I want to write a for loop that goes through all of the child controllers and runs a function in them. At the moment the code is only running the function in one instance of the child controller. How do I iterate through all instances of the controller, which are generated through ng-repeat?

Basically, on the click of the button the function in childController should be run 4 times, one for each controller generated on each 'set' in 'wordlistSets'.

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="setAll(true)">Select All</button><button ng-click="setAll(false)">DeselectAll</button>
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="set in wordlistSets" ng-controller="setController">
       <div class="parentSelector">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectAllChildren(set.content)" ng-checked="parentChecked">
       </div>

       <div ng-repeat="wordlist in set.content"  ng-click="toggleCheckbox(wordlist)">
          <input type="checkbox"  ng-checked="checkedWordlists.indexOf(wordlist)> -1">
       </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Angular controllers:

```
myApp.controller("parentController", function ($scope) {
   $scope.setAll = function(value) {
       var index;
       for (index in $scope.wordlistSets) {
           $scope.setAll.selectAllChildren($scope.wordlistSets[index].content, value);
       }
   };
});

myApp.controller("childController", function ($scope) {
$scope.parentChecked = false;
$scope.checkedWordlists = [];

$scope.selectAllChildren = function(wordlists) {
    if ($scope.parentChecked == false) {
        $scope.parentChecked = true;
    } else {
        $scope.parentChecked = false;
    }

    var index;
    for (index in wordlists) {
        $scope.setChild(wordlists[index], $scope.parentChecked);
    }
};

$scope.setAll.selectAllChildrenValue = function(wordlists, value) {
    if (value == false && $scope.parentChecked == true) {
        $scope.parentChecked = false;
    } else if (value == true && $scope.parentChecked == false) {
        $scope.parentChecked = true;
    }

    var index;
    for (index in wordlists) {
        $scope.setChild(wordlists[index], $scope.parentChecked);
    }
};

$scope.toggleCheckbox = function(wordlist) {
    var index = $scope.checkedWordlists.indexOf(wordlist);

    if (index > -1) {//is in array
        $scope.checkedWordlists.splice(index, 1);//remove from array
    } else {
        $scope.checkedWordlists.push(wordlist);//add to array
    }
};

$scope.setChild = function(wordlist, parentChecked) {
    var index = $scope.checkedWordlists.indexOf(wordlist);

    if (parentChecked && index <= -1) {//is not in array
        $scope.checkedWordlists.push(wordlist);//add to array
    } else if (!parentChecked && index > -1) {//is in array
        $scope.checkedWordlists.splice(index, 1);//remove from array
    }
};

});
```

Comment: The data all comes from the parent controller...so why can't you do what you need to there? What exactly is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Your question is not clear about what you want to accomplish. Please explain in more clear way. :)

Comment: Inside each <li> is a checkbox which then has a div of sub-checkboxes. I want clicking the button to select all checkboxes.

I will edit question now

Comment: You are thinking about it all backwards. Your data model drives the view....so you update the data model to make the view reflect changes. Don't think about the view first, or the html ... think about the data first and let angular do it's job managing the DOM

Comment: So I need to like, create a checkedCheckbox variable in my jSON data?

Comment: I know I didn't get many answers to this but it made me realize that I was in fact, thinking about it all backwards. I set up a "checked" property in my json data and just set this for ng-checked. As for the setAll function, i simply iterated through the JSON with a forEach and set each .checked value to = true/false. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I know I didn't get many answers to this but it made me realize that I was in fact, thinking about it all backwards. I set up a "checked" property in my json data and just set this for ng-checked. As for the setAll function, i simply iterated through the JSON with a forEach and set each .checked value to = true/false. Thanks everyone :)